# Does electric field strength inside a insulator depend on depth depth of penetration of the field?

Tags: electrostatics

Consider a charge 'Q' at a distance 'r' from a point 'A' inside an insulator (Coloured brown in the picture bbelow).

Now, will the strength of the electric field at A depend on the thickness of the insulator/dielectric?

[image]

In the above pictures will the electric field E at point A be the same in both cases?

Comment: Hint: what's the definition of "electric field strength" ?    Can you clarify: is the intent of the problem that all grounds are at infinite distance?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am comming from a background in Thermal/CFD and just trying to learn. My understanding is that Electric field strength is same as Electric filed or sometimes mean just the magnitude of the force. The intent is just to get an understanding. I couldn't find a lot on how Coulomb Law is different when the charges are in different materials. Will the addition of different materials.make the problem too complex? Can you please refer me to any notes if you know of them?